# ready function in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to write the jQuery ready function and then: 
 Inside the jQuery ready function, use jQuery to get all of the `<h2>` elements on the a new Git branch titled “headings” based off the “v0.1” tag with the following: page and assign them to a variable named headings;  Without creating any new variables, change the text of the last element of the headings variable to: “I’m firstname lastname, and I’m learning jQuery!” (replace “firstname lastname” with your first and last name).

Here is the jQuery I have, yet keep getting an error:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var headings = $('h2');
    $('headings').h2(3) 
                 .text ("I'm Arianna Delin, and I'm learning jQuery!");           
}).triggerHandler('change');
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you are missing }); at the end

Comment: 1) `$('headings')` is running a query against the DOM using the "headings" selector: it won't find anything. What you mean there is just `headings` (the variable). 2) jQuery has no `h2` function: if you want to retrieve the n-th element have a look at the selectors [:nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) and [:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) (from what you said I would say to also have a look at [:last](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) and [:last-child](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)). 3) what is the reason for the triggerHandler?

Comment: $(document) .ready (function(){
 var headings = $('h2'); 


$('h2') .eq (3).text (“I’m Arianna Delin, and I’m learning jQuery!”); 
});

Comment: This still gives me an error.

Answer (score 1):

Several issues:

- Missing closing of `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`
- `$('heading')` is a new DOM search for elements "heading" and not the variable - You should remove the quotes - `$(heading)` or better use `heading.last()`
- `h2(3)` not sure what you are doing there but if you want to target the last element then use `.last()`;
- If you are trying to get the third element the correct syntax will be `.eq(2)`;

So consider this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $("h2").last().text("your text");           
}).triggerHandler("change");

//Or:

$(function(){                       // Same as ready();
   $("h2").eq(2).text("your text"); // changes the third element
   $(document).trigger("change");       
});
```

A Quick demo: [**JSnippet Demo**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/504/)